# Has CPU inter-core communication become slower?

Tags: cpu, performance, intel-core-i7, multi-core, xeon

I'd be pretty amazed if it had but maybe somebody can help me understand.

I ran SiSoft Sandra Lite 2014's 'Processor Multi-Core Efficiency' test (which returns an 'Inter-Core Bandwidth' value) on my i7-9700K (stock clocks) and got a result of 11GB/s.

I also had a result noted down from years ago on an overclocked (4GHz) old socket 1366 CPU (would have been either an i7-920 or Xeon X5670) which achieved 26GB/s.

Any ideas why a pre-Sandy Bridge CPU would have scored so much higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the
[SiSoft Intel Core i7-9700K results](https://ranker.sisoftware.co.uk/show_device.php?q=c9a598d1bfcbaec2e2a1cebcd9f990a78ab384b484cfe98eb385a3d1ecddfb92af9fb9d1ecdcfa82bf8fa9cca994a482f1ccf4&l=en),
the average score is 11-12 GB/s, which agrees with your findings.

The real craziness is found in the
[Xeon X5670 result](https://ranker.sisoftware.co.uk/top_device.php?q=c2ffc9ef82efd2f486bb8badc4f9c9ef87ba8aacd4e9d9ff9affc2f0c3f2dce9cfbc81b0&l=en)
which vary greatly between 14.78 GB/s, 45.80 GB/s, and 35.40 GB/s.

My conclusion is that results are heavily dependent on the architecture of the
computer, such as the memory architecture (channels etc.), memory controller
and memory speed and probably also CPU and operating system.

In some recent computers, the memory controller has migrated from the motherboard
to the CPU, which might also affect, or even invalidate, the methodology of the
SiSoft benchmark.

In short, the SiSoft number is probably meaningless and doesn't measure
what it is supposed to be testing. I would suggest not to take it too
seriously, especially if your new computer is evidently faster than
the old one.

Comment: Good thinking - completely slipped my mind that these results are uploaded to their website! But Nehalem and Westmere (the 1st gen i3/i5/i7 architecture that these old CPUs are built on) actually did have integrated memory controllers (first architecture to do so). They do make use of a triple-channel memory architecture but aggregate bandwidth would still be lower than that of the modern setup (3x 1600/12800 vs 2x 3200/25600). You are probably right though that we can write it off as a software flaw.